# Get users that are presidents and compute their name

Tags: php, laravel

I have a **user table** like this

```
id | firstname | surname  | title 
1  | Bob       | Batman   | Dr.
2  | Alice     | Grimley  | Prof.
3  | Clara     | Caprio   |
```

In the **user model** class I have a function that computes the name

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    //...

    public function computeName()
    {
      return  trim($this->title . ' ' . $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->surname);
    }

    //...
}
```

In addition I have a **1:n** relation with a table `sortUser2Pres` where `n` can only be 0 or 1. The relation maps if a user is a president or vice-president in a country.

```
user_id | country | type 
1       | DE      | vice-president
2       | DE      | president
```

Now I wish to compute a name list of all users who are president. I can achieve it as follows:

```
$presidents = DB::table('user')
               ->select('firstname','surname','title')
               ->join('sortUser2Pres s', 's.user_id','=','user.id')
               ->where('s.type','president')
               ->get();

$names =  [];
foreach ($presidents as $user) {
    $names[] = trim($->title . ' ' . $->firstname . ' ' . $user->surname);
}
```

However, I think its bad that I cannot make use of the functions from the user model like `computeName` and that I have to copy & paste this function. Isn't there a cleaner way of achieving such a name list in Laravel and making use of the existing functions in the user model?

Comment: Dr. Bob Batman here - I don't recall giving you permission to use my name.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. sorry I did't use your name, this is a real backup from my porn site user table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you have a `1:n` relation? you can just add a `1:1` or column to your `user` table which has a `type` column for example and it holds `president` or `vice-president` values and then you can have a function in your model to check if it's a `president` or `vice-president`.

You can add a function to your `repository` to get all user which they are `president` with a simple query.

Comment: Your right a `1:n` relation is unnecessary one can use  the `hasOne` relation. And my question was basically how to write the simple query for that, but I found out now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your main problem is that you cannot reuse `computeName()` and that's because you've decided to couple it to the user model object, the nail in the coffin for that coupling was using `$this` there's a few ways to uncouple that at run time but you'd be better off without the coupling in the first place:

Since it seems like you need computeName() outside of the context of the model object I think it's time to decouple your method into its own function and then reuse it wherever you need it :

```
function compute_name(string $title, string $firstname, string $surname) : string
{
  return trim($title . ' ' . $firstname . ' ' . $surname);
}
```

I'd also consider renaming the function, 'compute' seems redundant, as does the `trim()` function unless you're absolutely sure you have white space at the beginning of your titles or end of your surnames, in which case I would ask why that wasn't stripped before it reached the database

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I did not want to uncouple the method, I just wanted to know how to use the query, but I found out by now. I think your right, `computeName` is a bad function name. Probably better to use something like `fullName()`. The `trim()` function is necessary though. The input in my database is stripped, but not every user has a `title` so I have to trim `($title . ' ' . $name`

Comment: You could add fullName() to your object as long as you stop using ```$this``` in your method, it can be used it both call points by supplying the arguments ```$user->fullName($title, $firstname, $surname);```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it:

I used a `hasOne` relation in the `user` class because it can be used if you need  a `hasOneOrZero` relation ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866046/does-laravel-have-a-one-to-zero-or-one-eloquent-relation)

```
public function president()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Profile\President','idMember');
}
```

Now that I didn't have a pivot table anymore, I stored the `type` column in the `president` table and thus I could change the query to

```
$presidents = User::select('firstname','surname','title')
                    ->whereHas('president', function($q){
                       $q->where('type','president')
                     })
                     ->get();


$names =  [];
foreach ($presidents as $user) {
    $names[] = $user->computeName();
}
```

By the way, if you wanted to keep the relation as a `1:n` relation than the query should be called like this:

```
$presidents = User::select('firstname','surname','title')
                    ->whereHas('president', function($q){
                       $q->where('sortUser2Pres.type','president')
                     })
                     ->get();
```

where `sortUser2Pres` is the pivot table.